# Accidental occurrence of environ["REQUEST_METHOD"] key error on production server, with flask+uwsgi service mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, uwsgi

This error occasionally occurs on the production server, which using flask combine uwsgi and nginx. My python version is 2.7.9 and flask version is 0.12.
Can someone help me solve this problem?

What I can see in the traceback below is the REQUEST_METHOD parameter is missing from the environment variable uwsgi passes to flask app.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projects/igor/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/projects/igor/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1977, in wsgi_app
    ctx = self.request_context(environ)
  File "/home/projects/igor/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1938, in request_context
    return RequestContext(self, environ)
  File "/home/projects/igor/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.url_adapter = app.create_url_adapter(self.request)
  File "/home/projects/igor/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1765, in create_url_adapter
    server_name=self.config['SERVER_NAME'])
  File "/home/projects/igor/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1524, in bind_to_environ
    environ["REQUEST_METHOD"],
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
```